# Powershell: splitting a string into an *array* of strings

Tags: arrays, string, powershell

I have a string consisting of values separated by a defined symbol. I need to convert it to another string containing the same values in the reverse order.

At the first sight, the task looks trivial. Using `-split` to split the string into an array of strings and then using `[array]::reverse` function along with `-join`.

The task is done? Wrong. Reverse function requires an object of Array type as a parameter, and `-split` returns an object of String type even it looks like an array. Reverse function simply doesn't work with it and returns an empty value.

Of course, there always is a classic C-like solution with For cycle:

```
$arr = $str1.split(".")
$str2 = ""
for ($i = $arr.length-1; $i -ge 0; $i--) {
   $str2 += $arr[$i]
}
```

However, in PS, it looks crude and ineffective. Is there another, more elegant solution that could solve the same task without using For? Some way to split a string into an array-type object with a single operator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `[array]::Reverse` is an in-place operation, which means that it directly operate on the array and modify the elements in place.

```
PS> $str = "H.I.1"
PS> $tmp = $str.split(".")
PS> [array]::Reverse($tmp)
PS> $tmp
1
I
H
```

To confirm this we can check the function signature.

```
PS> [array]::reverse

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
static void Reverse(array array)
static void Reverse(array array, int index, int length)
```

As you can see it return `void`, which means that function does not return anything instead it directly operate on the array